# Is there anything like an audio equivalent for <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, browser, audio

I'm wondering if there are any plug-ins/libraries or awesome tools that would let me script sound/music with javascript in a browser in a similar way to how `<canvas>` allows you to script drawing and animations.

Comment: Just a comment. I generally find music on a webpage very annoying. Especially unexpected music. It hearkens back to the 90's when every page had an embedded MIDI file on loop. Of course it depends what your website is about.

Comment: Are you looking for browser based midi?

Comment: If you're talking down to the sample level, you may find http://vocamus.net/dave/?cat=25 interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- it's not yet ready for mainstream use, but they're working on it!

There's a nascent JavaScript [audio data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) being actively hacked on by the mozilla group, and the W3C standards body has formed an [Audio Incubator Group](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/audio/) with a view to make the standards.

For more information about this effort, and how people are using the API, you could read these [two](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2010/05/03/real-sound-synthesis-now-an-open-standard-in-the-browser/) [posts](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2010/05/27/browser-madness-3d-music-mountainscapes-web-based-pd-patching/) from createdigitalmusic.com , or read the [announcement](http://weblog.bocoup.com/web-audio-all-aboard) from the people working on the API.

I believe you'll need a development build of firefox to use it at this stage--its still very much developer-ware.

If however you need to reach a wide audience with your browser-based synthesis, without waiting for this to become standard, you'll need to use a browser plugin like flash or Java in the meantime.

If you only need to trigger samples of pre-recorded or pre-generated audio, then you could use the `<audio>` tag. But if you want to do your own synthesis, you'll need a lower level API like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Latest browsers support the `<audio>` tag, so you could use that depending on your requirements for browser support.